# How to kill KDB queries in RDB or HDB?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

We have a ticker plant and sometimes someone mistakenly runs queries in HDB without a date or in RDB without a time or with some other processing logic which may kill KDB. How can we find and kill the query without restarting KDB instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set client query time out in your service:

param:  '-T '

reference: http://code.kx.com/q4m3/13_Commands_and_System_Variables/#13121-timeout-t

**From wiki:** The timeout parameter (note upper case) is an int that specifies the number of seconds any call from a client will execute before it is timed out and terminated. The default value is 0 which means no timeout. This parameter corresponds to the command \T.

**Ex:**  start your q process as:

```
       q -T 40
```

it will set client query timeout to 40 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rahul says, you can use T for timeout.

If you're on a unix system you can also `kill -SIGINT <pid>` - which kills the current thread. In multithreaded mode you might get mixed results though.

Comment: Does kdb query gets a separate thread to execute? Will it not affect kdb?

Comment: If it's the current running thread and it's single-threaded KDB instance then it'll just kill that thread, not the process. I've done this many times, works a treat :)